# UserControl switch

Tags: c#, user-controls

There are two different UserControls which share some common Properties.
What I'd like to do is to switch between these two based on an external flag.

```
UserControl u1, u2;

if(flag)
{
    u1 = u1 as ControlType1;
    u2 = u2 as ControlType1;
}
else
{
    u1 = u1 as ControlType2;
    u2 = u2 as ControlType2;
}

SomeMethod(u1.SelectedItemName, u2.SelectedItemName);
```

Since UserControl doesn't have a property called "SelectedItemName", the code would not throw error.

What I've currently done is, I've added an extension method on UserControl which gets the "SelectedItemName" using reflection, and I get the value by calling u1.SelectedItemName() instead of u1.SelectedItemName;

My question is what is an easy way to fix this without using extension/ maybe the right way. Note that I don't want to repeat the SomeMethod(a,b) inside the if statement.

Comment: If `u1` is defined as type `UserControl`, then what is the point of saying `u1 = u1 as ControlType`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make both of these `UserControl` classes implement a shared interface or derive from a shared base class.  You could then develop against the base class or interface without worrying about the flags/switches at all.

```
IYourUserControl u1, u2;

SomeMethod(u1, u2);
```

This would work provided SomeMethod was defined as:

```
void SomeMethod(IYourUserControl one, IYourUserControl two) { // ...
```

Comment: this is what I want suggest too, interface :)

Comment: I do not have control over the user controls, but I agree with you   that this is the right way.

Comment: @edocetirwi With no control over the user controls, reflection is probably the only way to get there.  It's just ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this isntead:

```
UserControl u1, u2;

if(flag)
{
    u1 = u1 as ControlType1;
    u2 = u2 as ControlType1;
    SomeMethod((u1 as ControlType1).SelectedItemName, (u2 as ControlType1).SelectedItemName);
}
else
{
    u1 = u1 as ControlType2;
    u2 = u2 as ControlType2;
    SomeMethod((u1 as ControlType2).SelectedItemName, (u2 as ControlType2).SelectedItemName);
}
```

Or, if you create a `BaseControlType` that contains `SelectedItemName` and which `ControlType1` and `ControlType2` extend from, you could do this:

```
UserControl u1, u2;

if(flag)
{
    u1 = u1 as ControlType1;
    u2 = u2 as ControlType1;
}
else
{
    u1 = u1 as ControlType2;
    u2 = u2 as ControlType2;
}

SomeMethod((u1 as BaseControlType).SelectedItemName, (u2 as BaseControlType).SelectedItemName);
```

Comment: I just adde that I do not want to repeat that SomeMethod() twice;  Apologize for not adding that in question.

Comment: Then you should have a BaseControlType that contains the property "SelectedItemName" that you can cast to, which you can use in the `SomeMethod(...)` call. See my edit.